# Why does udev automatically whitelist my RAID card and what is the function of this whitelisting?

Tags: udev, devices, raid

I've been learning to use udev and noticed that when I run `udevadm test --action="add" /sys/block/sdc` I see the following:

```
GROUP 6 /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:59
IMPORT 'scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d /dev/sdc' /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:50
starting 'scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d /dev/sdc'
'scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d /dev/sdc'(out) 'ID_SCSI=1'
'scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d /dev/sdc'(out) 'ID_VENDOR=NVMe'
'scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d /dev/sdc'(out) 'ID_VENDOR_ENC=NVMe\x20\x20\x20\x20'
'scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d /dev/sdc'(out) 'ID_MODEL=Dell_Ent_NVMe_v2'
'scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d /dev/sdc'(out) 'ID_MODEL_ENC=Dell\x20Ent\x20NVMe\x20v2'
'scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d /dev/sdc'(out) 'ID_REVISION=.2.0'
'scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d /dev/sdc'(out) 'ID_TYPE=disk'
'scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d /dev/sdc'(out) 'ID_SERIAL=236435330529024120025384100000002'
'scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d /dev/sdc'(out) 'ID_SERIAL_SHORT=36435330529024120025384100000002'
'scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d /dev/sdc'(out) 'ID_SCSI_SERIAL=S6CSNA0R902412      '
Process 'scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d /dev/sdc' succeeded.
```

sdc in this case is a virtual disk sitting on a PERC H755. I have not yet changed anything in udev.

The above is what you see when using a RAID0 (passthrough/JBOD mode). If you create a RAID 5 you see

```
probe /dev/sda raid offset=0
LINK 'disk/by-id/wwn-0x6f4ee080160bd5002ab7652100a1691a' /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:97
IMPORT '/usr/bin/sg_inq --export --inhex=/sys/block/sda/device/inquiry --raw' /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-scsi-sg3_id.rules:17
starting '/usr/bin/sg_inq --export --inhex=/sys/block/sda/device/inquiry --raw'
'/usr/bin/sg_inq --export --inhex=/sys/block/sda/device/inquiry --raw'(out) 'SCSI_TPGS=0'
'/usr/bin/sg_inq --export --inhex=/sys/block/sda/device/inquiry --raw'(out) 'SCSI_TYPE=disk'
'/usr/bin/sg_inq --export --inhex=/sys/block/sda/device/inquiry --raw'(out) 'SCSI_VENDOR=DELL'
'/usr/bin/sg_inq --export --inhex=/sys/block/sda/device/inquiry --raw'(out) 'SCSI_VENDOR_ENC=DELL\x20\x20\x20\x20'
'/usr/bin/sg_inq --export --inhex=/sys/block/sda/device/inquiry --raw'(out) 'SCSI_MODEL=PERC_H755N_Front'
'/usr/bin/sg_inq --export --inhex=/sys/block/sda/device/inquiry --raw'(out) 'SCSI_MODEL_ENC=PERC\x20H755N\x20Front'
'/usr/bin/sg_inq --export --inhex=/sys/block/sda/device/inquiry --raw'(out) 'SCSI_REVISION=5.16'
```

My question is how is udev "deciding" to whitelist the PERC and what is the function of whitelisting?

### Research Done

- Read through [this post](https://www.wilgysef.com/linux-usb-whitelist/) on whitelisting for USB drives but this seems to be used when someone makes the decision to manually disallow all USB devices except certain targets which isn't applicable here.
- [This tutorial on writing udev scripts](https://opensource.com/article/18/11/udev) but it didn't answer any of my questions about whitelisting.
- [The udev Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) but while that gave me a better architectural understanding it didn't help me with whitelisting
- [The man page for udev](https://linux.die.net/man/8/udev) - helpful but no mention of whitelisting.

In general I tried Googling for results related to udev whitelisting but the only results I could find were all about whitelisting USB devices rather than how whitelisting generally functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The --whitelisted option appears to do a "wet run" (as opposed to "dry run") because without it `scsi_id` does not appear to be doing anything at all.

see source: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/bab787396444466e5a71e5f01b1924646959f6e0/src/udev/scsi_id/scsi_id.c#L407

```
static int scsi_id(char *maj_min_dev) {
        int good_dev;
        (...)

        per_dev_options(&dev_scsi, &good_dev, &page_code);
        if (!good_dev) {
                retval = 1;
                goto out;
        }
        (...)
out:
        return retval;


static int per_dev_options(struct scsi_id_device *dev_scsi, int *good_bad, int *page_code) {

        (...)

        while (retval == 0) {
                option = getopt_long(newargc, newargv, "bgp:", options, NULL);
                if (option == -1)
                        break;

                switch (option) {
                case 'b':
                        *good_bad = 0;
                        break;

                case 'g':
                        *good_bad = 1;
                        break;


static void help(void) {
               (...)
               "  -b --blacklisted                 Treat device as blacklisted\n"
               "  -g --whitelisted                 Treat device as whitelisted\n"
               (...)
```

this is from a ubuntu 22 system:

```
root@trybase:~# /usr/lib/udev/scsi_id /dev/sdc 
root@trybase:~# /usr/lib/udev/scsi_id  --whitelisted /dev/sdc 
35000c500c7869d5b
```

Comment: How did you know that scsi_id was associated with systemd?

Comment: locate scsi_id gave me this: `/home/jaroslav/src/github.com/systemd/systemd/src/udev/scsi_id`. I had a copy of systemd checked out for some reason... You could have had some luck with:
apt-file search  scsi_id (debian), e-file scsi_id (gentoo)

Comment: I think systemd just has a clone of udev in the source, so the scsi_id program is actually from udev, not systemd.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин [udev is part of systemd](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Udev-will-become-part-of-systemd-1500832.html).

Comment: Good to know! thanks.